# Filling an array

Tags: ajax, arrays

My question is to fill an arrary with data from an ajax request.  My ajax call receives the data fine and is logged n the console.  What I'm having difficulty with is filling my array with that data.  Here is my code.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: WebRoot + "ws/GIS.asmx/CensusData",
        data: d,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //loop through the data and pull out the fips codes                
            //alert("success");
            fipsData = data;



            console.log(fipsData);
        } //ends success function
    });  //ends ajax call
```

Comment: Want to post the result of that `console.log(fipsData);`

Comment: Can you show the result of log? or the url for get your json?

Comment: console.log(fipsData) is empty [] but console.log(data) returns to columns of data one my fips code and my amount

Comment: For what ever reasons using fipsData = data.d is filling the array with the object

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSON.parse() like this:

```
fipsData = JSON.parse(data);
```

and you should be good to go.